# What is this User parameter in Django?

Tags: python, django

> **What is the User model we are importing here? What does it do
> here?**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Customer(models.Model):
            user=models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            name=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
            phone=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
            email=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
            profile_pic=models.ImageField(default="profile2.png",null=True,blank=True)
        
            def __str__(self):
                return self.name
```

Comment: It's the User model built into Django by default for authentication. And honestly, I feel you need to run through some tutorials first before turning to SO ... I can recommend the  Django Girls tutorial - it's extremely good for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

```
user=models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Above line is making a one-to-one relationship with the default Django User model with the customer model. This means, every User instance in your database can be associated with atmost 1 Customer instance.

- The default User model contains standard user fields like username, email, first_name, last_name etc. Take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/) to learn more about the User model.
- Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) to learn more about one-to-one relationships.